# Find statistics over same shape arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, statistics

Hello So I'm trying to map the pearson R statistic for some data. However the data is over arrays. I have made the arrays The same shape and size however no matter what I do the code won't run instead giving me the error:
'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

```
f = netCDF4.Dataset('C:/data/Feb.nc',
                        'r')
    # Import variables
    v = f.variables['store_Bio'][0:28, 0:24, 0, 0:60, 0:60])/81
    t = f.variables['temp_a'][0:28, 0:24, 0, :, :]
    g = f.variables['skin_temp'][0:28, 0:24, :, :]
    cc = f.variables['cloud_cover'][0:28, 0:24, 0, :, :]


    # Mean over array to make them the same shape
    v1 = v.mean(axis=(0, 1))
    t1 = t.mean(axis=(0, 1))
    g1 = g.mean(axis=(0, 1))
    cc1 = cc.mean(axis=(0, 1))

    # Pearson R stats
    p11 = pearsonr(v1, t1)
    p21 = pearsonr(v1, g1)
    p31 = pearsonr(v1, cc1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input type of [pearsonr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) should be array like.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> pearsonr(a,b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 2518, in pearsonr
    r = max(min(r, 1.0), -1.0)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> pearsonr(a.ravel(),b.ravel())
(1.0, 0.0)
```

For each corresponding value you can try the following code snipped. It will give you a `result` array equal to the size of your input.

```
>>> result = [pearsonr(x, y) for x, y in zip(a,b)]
```

Comment: I can see how that would get you the 1 r stat for the whole array.  However, I want to get r stats for each corresponding value within the array. So the result is an array of the same size containing r statistics.

Comment: Hello , This results in an array that is 60x2 in opposed to 60x60x2

Comment: I am writing the answer without knowing the data format/shape you are working on. It would be better if you could tell something about the data format/shape. Besides, this is a generalized idea. You should change it in accordance to your need easily.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad! So v1:60,60 t1:60,60 and g1:60,60. Basically the data is just in grids

Comment: how exactly do I change this to suit my needs? I really have no idea :/